# How to add symbols on edges to say they are same length?

Tags: latex, tikz

There are some edges having the same length. I want to add little symbol on it as in the picture:

[image]

How do I do? Thanks.

```latex
 \begin{tikzpicture}      
  \coordinate (Base1) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (Base2) at (4,0);
  \coordinate (Base3) at (5,2);
  \coordinate (TopPt) at (2,5);

  \draw [draw=black, every edge/.append style={draw=black, dashed}]
  (Base1) -- (Base2) --(Base3) 
  (Base3) edge (Base1);

  \draw [draw=black, every edge/.append style={draw=black, dashed}]
  (TopPt) -- (Base1) 
  (TopPt) -- (Base2) 
  (TopPt) -- (Base3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Have a look at the package `tkz-euclide` here: http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/tkz-euclide-screen.pdf.  The section 12.3.2 is relevant to this question.

Comment: In English: http://www.altermundus.fr/downloads/documents/Sangaku.pdf

Comment: Perhaps [Marking angles in a parallelogram congruent using TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/253007) is of interest.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need the tikz *decoration* library (both `decorations` and `decorations.markings`):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}      
  \coordinate (Base1) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (Base2) at (4,0);
  \coordinate (Base3) at (5,2);
  \coordinate (TopPt) at (2,5);

  \draw [draw, every edge/.append style={draw, dashed}]
  (Base1) -- (Base2) -- (Base3) 
  (Base3) edge (Base1);

  \draw [draw]
  (TopPt) -- (Base1) 
  (TopPt) -- (Base2)
  (TopPt) -- (Base3);
  \draw [draw,decoration={markings, mark=at position .5  with {\node[transform shape] {$\parallel$};}}]
  (TopPt) edge[decorate] (Base1) 
  (TopPt) edge[decorate] (Base2)
  (TopPt) edge[decorate] (Base3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]